# how to CSS3 transform and rotate only at the end

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to have a block of DIV to move to the right by 300px, THEN rotate about the Y axis by 180deg, move back to the origin X position, then rotate about the Y axis by 180deg.

```
 |-->---->----->------|
rotate             rotate
 |----<-----<-----<---|
```

What I have now rotates and moves at the same time. Is there any way I can define these transformations step by step?

http://jsbin.com/nomuqe/edit?html,css,output

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set more keyframes with the required values.

Since you want to make the rotation keeping the same position (translation), you need to set 2 keyframes with the same translate value and changing only the rotation

```css
.test{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0px 20px;
  background: orange; 
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(0px)  rotateY(0deg);
  }
  49%{
    transform: translateX(300px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateX(300px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(0px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: Hi Vals! Thanks for the quite answer! Can you explain also why both 49 and 50% have the translateX(300px?)

Comment: Added more detail in the answer